# WORD VBA Search and switch to advanced

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

Need your help. And I know in advance that the built-in "CTRL + H" function is supposed to give an appropriate answer - but in my case it is not. Because of text language issues, and because I have a lot of characters that are not "letters or numbers" - the usual search and swap causes mistakes.

And now for the request - and many many thanks in advance!

I was able to "scrape" and revamp a relatively simple code, which performs a search and replacement of the entire document, to which I was able to thread MSGBOX for requests confirmation for each replacement:

"OK" button - confirms a single replacement.
"No" button - skips this search - and does not make a switch.
"Cancel" button - stops the macro.

1. How do you add a fourth button that will perform "Replace All"?
2. Is there a "count-down" option for running without user intervention? I want the default to be "Ok", and even if I did not press, then after 3 seconds - a change will be made.
3. I've been breaking my head for many days - and can not convert this code that will only work in selected / marked text.

HERE IS THE CODE I USE

```
Sub Want2Replace()
  Dim myRange As Range
  Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
  myRange.Find.ClearFormatting
  myRange.Find.MatchWildcards = True
  Dim cached As Long
  cached = myRange.End
      Do While myRange.Find.Execute("åÀ")
          myRange.Select
          MyAnswer = MsgBox("Replace " & myRange.Find.Text & "?", vbYesNoCancel)
              If MyAnswer = vbYes Then Call Shva_Na
              If MyAnswer = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
                  myRange.Start = myRange.Start + Len(myRange.Find.Text)
                  myRange.End = cached
      Loop
  End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot add buttons to a message box. You can only use the standard options.

Comment: You can create a UserForm for more flexibility/power. http://www.gmayor.com/Userform.htm

Comment: A message box cannot give you the buttons! Have you looked into using a UserForm?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, you can write a second function with ReplaceAll or adapt your function according to user expectations.

You can also add another MsgBox that asks for ReplaceAll.

So you have to decide and answer yourself the question whether the user actually wants `ReplaceAll` and/or a single `Replace` is a special function as an additional function.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the answers.
As mentioned, the difficulty is that sometimes a replacement deletes additional characters that were "swallowed" in the search result.
This question should remain open: There are situations where the user knows in advance that he is allowing himself to "ReplaceAll", and he is not expected to be surprised, and there are situations where he prefers to check a few cases, and only then switch to use "ReplaceAll".